# Difference between two maps when updating field in cloud firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
var data = {
  'key.number': 1,
};

var data = {
  'key' : {
    'number': 1,
  }
};
```

Is there any difference between the two `Map`s when updating `number` on the cloud firestore using

```
var ref = Firestore.instance.document('users/id');
ref.updateData(data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the document didn't already have a "key" field, there is no difference.

If the document *did* already have a "key" field, the first one would just overwrite any existing value for `key.field`, *preserving* any other fields in the key object, and the second one would *completely overwrite* the key object and all of its existing fields.

Comment: Great, thank you, but how can someone type this fast, in a minute you wrote such a great answer, heads off to you :)

Comment: In case "key" exists, is second case equivalent to `ref.setData(data, merge: true)`?

Comment: Any update is the same as set with merge if the entire document already exists.  Set with merge just creates the document if it didn't already exists, while update just fails of the document is missing.